# How to change input label value programmaly using Angular

Tags: html, angular, label

So I have 2 fields that can be filled in the `UI` and it works but how can I fill the UI programmatically.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="durationText">Song Duration (ms)</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="durationText" id="durationText" placeholder="Song Duration">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="pitchfile">Pitches file (.txt)</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="pitchfile" accept=".txt" (change)="setPitchfile($event)">
</div>
```

[image]

And in the `.ts` file I have:

```
durationText : "";
pitchfile: any;
```

And i want to set it like:

```
durationText = "120";
```

But it does not let me so what should I do ?
And how do I set the file `pitchfile` programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### UPDATE 1:

There's an issue with your code.

```
durationText : "";
pitchfile: any;
```

Should have been:

```
durationText : string;
pitchfile: any;
```

---

### UPDATE 2:

In case this was a text file that you were accepting and the user selected the file via an `input` type file, you could read the contents of it using this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent {
  durationText;

  setPitchfile($event) {...}

  readFromTextFile($event) {
    const file = $event.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {
      console.log(reader.result);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
  }

  ...

}
```

The Sample StackBlitz is updated accordingly.

---

### ORIGINAL ANSWER:

Not really sure how you'll be able to get the duration from a text file.

**But if you have an actual audio file, you can do something like this:**

You can create a `new Audio()` instance and then set it's `src` property using `URL.createObjectURL($event.target.files[0]);`. Once the metadata is loaded, the Audio instance fires a `loadedmetadata` event to which you can listen to assigning a function to the `onloadedmetadata` on the audio instance.

Inside this callback function, you can check for the `duration` property.

Give this a try:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent {
  durationText = '';

  setPitchfile($event) {
    console.log($event.target.files);

    const audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = URL.createObjectURL($event.target.files[0]);
    audio.onloadedmetadata = () => {
      console.log(audio.duration);
      this.durationText = audio.duration;
    };

  }

  ...

}
```

---

Here's a [**Working Sample Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-duration-eg?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: Duration is just a string in my example (or atleast should be) and when I try to set it with `this.durationText = "231"`. I get this error : "TS2322: Type '"231"' is not assignable to type '"".  And the `pitchfile` would be an actual file which I would get from the server. I am sorry for not giving enough information in the beginning.

Comment: `durationText : "";` should have been `durationText : string;` This would fix the error you're getting.

Comment: Your answer does a bit too much but I can use it and replace the duration. The point of my question was to how to set `duration` programmatically and how to set the file the same way. Without interacting with the UI.

Comment: For that I guess you'll have to read the txt file and then based on that set the `durationText`. What exactly is the content of your file?

Comment: `pitchfile` would be `.mp3`. Also by chaning it to `durationText : string;` resolved my issue, sorry if that seemed a little dumb.

Comment: God! Why does your OP say it would be a text file in that case? It's confusing. Can you please update that. Also in that case, I think my answer would be accurate. I assumed pitchFile to be an audio file.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, and thank you for your time, that answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple, you need to add 'name' attribute to your input like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="durationText" id="durationText" name="durationText" placeholder="Song Duration">
```